# Почему не работает переменная js?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

у меня есть переменная  **var a**
которую нужно передать в *datepicker* **datesDisabled: a**

но ничего не происходит, я в этом деле новичок по этому не знаю тонкостей этого дела.

```
function bookingload(){
        var a = "что то";

 $('.datepicker1, .datepicker2').datepicker({
    language: "ru",
    datesDisabled: a
 });

 }

window.addEventListener('load', bookingload, false);
```

Comment: а что должно происходить? приведенный код делает именно то, что требуется - значение переменной присваивается в соответствующую настройку

Comment: @Grundy должно передавать дату вообще

Comment: судя по названию. скорее список дат. Что за datepicker используется? что написано в справке по этому полю?

Comment: @Grundy https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=-&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&todayHighlight=on&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox

Comment: @Grundy да как то вообще не описано почему все это происходит

Comment: [справка](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#datesdisabled) - какое значение ты присваиваешь переменной?

Comment: @Grundy 10.10.2010